# Set navigation buttons back to old layout on Samsung tablet Android 13

Tags: samsung, tablet, navigation-bar, android-13

I have two Samsung Galaxy A8 Tablets.

One runs Android 13, the other one 12.
How do I get the navigation buttons on the bottom (not sure what they are called) back to the Android 12 layout?

I don't need the quick start apps options in the middle.
I want the navigation button there and not on the right.

Android 12 (this is how it should be)

[image]

Android 13 (Quick start apps & button on the right, this should be the same layout as the image above)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The thing is called "Symbol/Task bar" (Translated from Germany, not sure if its correct)

**Settings > Display > "Symbol/Task Bar"**

[image]